# Wrong getting value when key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, input

I try to get value from text input when key is down.

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" onkeydown="console.log(this.value)">
</body>
</html>
```

**Code demo:** http://jsbin.com/funexipure/1/edit?html,console,output

**Trouble description:** 
When I write `1` I have `""` as value in console.
When I write `2` after this I have `"1"` as value in console, and so on

So, How I can get actual current value when key is down? Thank you very much.

Comment: onkeydown is called before the input's value is changed, so you can return false to "ignore" a keystroke

Comment: I get the behaviour you describe for IE when I test your live example in Chrome.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I've noticed this problem, too and update my question. Thank you

Comment: Use `onkeyup` it fires when the key is released meaning the value will be set at that point, and for the love of god please don't use DOM attributes for event handlers.

Comment: @AlexanderSeredenko - a code example of what?

Comment: @ste2425 Yes, It works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onkeyup`to get what desire output is

```
  <input type="text" onkeyup="console.log(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyup function is quite good but it doesn't work if you paste the value with mouse click.

Try this

```
$('input').on('input propertychange', function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
})
```

This will work in keyboard typing also when you paste with mouse click.

**Reason**

`keyup` check when you press the key from keyboard but `propertychange` work when you change any property anyway.